# Should I define my SQL statement statement handle using separate variables in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, function, methods

### Are all 3 options the same (Y/N) or is one better (A/B/C)?

**Option A** -  (1) defining the SQL string in the variable `$sql` and (2) define the statement handle using the "method" `prepare` on the variable `$sql` to compose the statement and (3) activating composition of the statement in step 2 using the execute function.

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM table1";
    $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $sth->execute();
```

**Option B** - Similar to Option C because the `->query` method is used directly on the db object and similar to Option A in that the sql statement is kept separate.

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM table1";
    $sth = $dbh->query($sql);
```

**Option C** - The statement handle is the sql query itself (no reference to any another variables and just using one method.

```
    $sth = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM table1");
```

Questions:

Do both options yield the same result?

If they yield the same result, is one approach recommended (i.e. best practice)?

Did I get the vocabulary like "variable", "method", and "function" correct?

Does Option A still query the db despite not explicitly using the `->query()` method?

What are the pros/cons of including the sql stmnt in a seperate variable vs in the PDO Statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say both methods are the same about using a string variable or direct text string.

Assuming you using PDO there is difference between prepare statement and invoke a query statement.

In case A, the prepare statement will make the database create a plan so that statement can be reexecuted without reparsing the query string.

In case B the query is executed at once.

In your given example case B would run a little bit faster.
But if your statement uses arguments case A would benefit you with additional security due to placeholders been replaced by the driver.

Comment: I see.. so one issue I have "string variable" vs. "direct text string" and another issue is the difference between the prepare statement and the query statement. I am (trying) to use PDO.

Not sure what I will do next with the query, but just wanted to make sure I was pulling up the data the best way possible.

You refer to the "prepare statement" and "query statement" as "statements" are they methods or PDO statements? Thanks!!

Comment: They are methods of PDO ( $pdo->prepare, $pdo->query ) class. Your $dbh variable must be of PDO class( $dbh instanceof PDO ). Both methods returns an object which class is PDOStatement.

Answer (score 2):

> Do both options yield the same result?

Yes.

> If they yield the same result, is one approach recommended (i.e. best practice)?

Both are fine. In your particular example Option B gets the same job done with less code.

However, if you need to use parameters and/or constraints in your query (e.g. ...WHERE id = :id) you need to opt for option A to bind params using the $dbh->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT) method after your prepare your statement, e.g:

```
$dbh->prepare('UPDATE table SET column = :value WHERE id = :id');
$dbh->bindParam(':value', $someNewValue, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$dbh->bindParam(':id', $targetId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$dbh->execute();
```

Doing it this way will also protect you from nasty things like SQL injections.

Storing the query in a separate variable is only needed if you plan to re-use that query at a later time in your code. Otherwise you might as well just type it within your prepare/query method directly.

> Did I get the vocabulary like "variable", "method", and "function" correct?

Looks about right! Except: "the execute function" is a method. Functions and methods are basically the same things except when they belong to an object they are referred to as methods. In your example execute belongs to the $sth object, so it's called a method.

> Does Option A still query the db despite not explicitly using the ->query() method?

Yes. The execute method executes the query that was prepared in $dbh->prepare(...). If you want to use parameters you can call ->bindParam() between your prepare and execute methods. If you don't need parameters, invoking ->query() directly is really the more convenient way to do it.

Comment: that is a great answer, thanks! I have posted a similar question that deals with yet another "string variable" and the link includes this code above (and all the other code in the program)

link: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14063932/1788087

Please answer if you can. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Glad it helped. The answer provided by cavila on your other question is good and should do the trick. It will show you what exactly goes wrong when you try to establish the database connection.